# Git (Sourcetree) issue after checkout

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm very beginner in Git. I learned how to use in terminal but now I use SourceTree. Everything was perfectly fine but time for first checkout has come. After checkout I moved forward with my task and now I have this two branches and I don't know how to push later changes to remote. On remote I only see that one I checked out. Should I set `master` to `HEAD`? I can type in terminal, I don't care about SourceTree.

[image: snippet from SourceTree]

Thank you for answers!

Comment: From what I understand, you want to remove the code you have done on (3 sty 2018 11:04) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to mix HEAD with the master/origin branch :**

Go in your HEAD, open the console:

```
// (You are currently working on a detached HEAD and not in a proper branch)

git checkout -b harvestFile // Checkout your detached HEAD to a new branch Properly
git checkout master // Go back to your master branch
git merge harvestFile // Merge HarvestFile into master
git push origin // Push master to your remote.
```

**If you want to replace master with your HEAD :**

Go in your HEAD, open the console: :

```
// (You are currently working on a detached HEAD and not in a proper branch)

git checkout -b harvestFile // Checkout your detached HEAD to a new branch Properly
git checkout master // Go back to your master branch
git merge -s ours harvestFile // Merge HarvestFile into master only keep harvestFile branch commits
git push origin // Push master to your remote.
```

**If you want to create a new remote branch with the code in your HEAD  :**

Go in your HEAD, open the console: :

```
// (You are currently working on a detached HEAD and not in a proper branch)

git checkout -b <branchname> // Checkout your detached HEAD to a new branch Properly

git push -u origin <branchname> // Push and create <branchname> on your remote.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various solution for this scenario

Assumption 
You are having 2 branches, branch A and B
First you commited on branch A and now you have some changes on branch B

Origin is your remote name 
Branch A cab be your master

1. Push your changes to remote in branch B
   `git push origin branch b`
2. Merging your changes to branch A and then pushing it 
   `git checkout branch A`
   `git merge branch B`
   `git push origin branchA` ( branch A can be master also)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I ran into some complications (conflict) but finally using Sourcetree I discard conflicted changes and all appeared in remote on new branch.

What I learned is that in case like this it's necessary to create new branch to move forward.

Below is terminal dump, if I done something wrong pleas correct me.

```
$ git checkout -b mailing
Switched to a new branch 'mailing'

.../APFA 1.0/APMailTool (mailing)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

.../APFA 1.0/APMailTool (master)
$ git merge mailing
Auto-merging AP_MailCreation.bas
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in AP_MailCreation.bas
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

.../APFA 1.0/APMailTool (master|MERGING)
$ git merge -s ours mailing
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```